# Joi - Access object item property from first element of array

Tags: javascript, joi

I have schema for my validation:

```js
const schema2 = Joi.object({
    benefits: Joi.array().items(Joi.object({
        specification: Joi.object({
            type: Joi.string().valid("ORDER_FIXED_DISCOUNT", "UNIT_PERCENTAGE_DISCOUNT").required(),
        }).required()
    })).min(1).max(1).required(),
    offerCriteria: Joi.array().items(Joi.object({
        type: Joi.string().valid("CONTAINS_OFFERS").required(),
        offers: Joi.array().items(Joi.object({
            quantity: Joi.number().when(Joi.ref("....benefits.0.specification.type"), {
                is: Joi.string().valid("ORDER_FIXED_DISCOUNT"),
                then: Joi.required(),
                otherwise: Joi.forbidden()
            }),
            promotionEntryPoint: Joi.boolean().when(Joi.ref("....benefits.0.specification.type"), {
                is: Joi.string().valid("ORDER_FIXED_DISCOUNT"),
                then: Joi.required(),
                otherwise: Joi.forbidden()
            })
        })).min(1).required()
    })).min(1).max(1).required()
});
```

My goal is to set required for `offerCriteria.offers.quantity` and `offerCriteria.offers.quantitypromotionEntryPoint` if `benefits.specification.type` is
`ORDER_FIXED_DISCOUNT` otherwise set to forbidden.

I have tried this when conditions, but none of them worked properly:

- "....benefits.specification.type",
- "....benefits.0.specification.type",
- Joi.ref("....benefits.0.specification.type"),
- Joi.ref("....benefits.specification.type")

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way to solve this:

```
quantity: Joi.number().when("$specification_type", {
                is: Joi.string().valid("ORDER_FIXED_DISCOUNT"),
                then: Joi.required(),
                otherwise: Joi.forbidden()
            }),
```

`$specification_type` is set in context when validating

```
schema.validate(data, {context: {specification_type: data.benefits[0].specification.type}}})
```

I'm still looking for a way to use schema not context.